# WCF Reuse Types

Tags: .net, silverlight, wcf

What does "Reuse Types in Referenced Assemblies" actualy do?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, it is used to share the definition of your data contracts between service and client.
It is very useful when you have calculated properties or helper methods in your data contracts.

It is also a way to avoid regenerating the service reference when only the data contracts changes.

Suppose you have two services using the same class A and expose methods with parameters or return values of type A. If you use regular service references in a client app that connects to both services, you will have two A classes in your client app and they are not even compatible.

If you put A into a separate assembly and share it between client and services (and define the "Reuse types..." in your service references), then you can reuse exactly the same class everywhere and avoid duplicating some classes.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Service Reference, it will not generate types if they exist in referenced assemblies.