# Generating client proxy from WCF Service

Tags: c#, initialization

Service side class with property:

```
[DataContract]
[Serializable]
public class BusMessage
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "report")]
    [DataMember(Name = "report")]
    public Boolean DeliveryReportRequest
    {
        get { return _deliveryReportRequest; }
        set { _deliveryReportRequest = value; }
    }

}
```

Client side property within class BusMessage generated with visual studio

```
 [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public bool report {
            get {
                return this.reportField;
            }
            set {
                if ((this.reportField.Equals(value) != true)) {
                    this.reportField = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("report");
                }
            }
        }
```

From the client side I want to have same DataMember attribute with property Name = "report" and class Property Named DeliveryReportRequest. How to achieve it?

Comment: Use a shared assembly referenced from both projects. In the Service Reference properties, activate the "reuse types from referenced assembies" feature.

Comment: Doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: "Doesn't work" does not help. This question describe what you are trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089281/wcf-reuse-types/5089848#5089848

Comment: Ok, so there is no automatic option. Understood, thanks :)